# something wrong with UIButton setImage

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

[image]I am attempting to make my own custom Facebook login button. I am close, but for some reason when I setImage on the UIButton it still has a really large frame that is pushing the text to the right and the icon to the right as well.

What am I missing? I tried setting the frame and that did not help. 
(The actual image is large, but .scaleAspetFit makes it look perfect, but I think the frame persists?)

```
let customFacebookButton: UIButton = {
        let view = UIButton()
        view.setImage(UIImage(named: "fb-logo"), for: .normal)
        view.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 4)
        view.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "3B5998")
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14),
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.init(hex: "#EFEFEF") ]
        let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Continue with Facebook", attributes: attributes)
        mutableAttributedString.append(string)
        view.setAttributedTitle(mutableAttributedString, for: .normal)
        return view
    }()
```

[image: Custom Facebook UIButton]

Comment: what is the size of fb-logo

Comment: the image is 500 x 500 pixels

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the size of image. Reduce the size of image. It will work perfectly.

I have tested you code with two image sizes 512*512 and 80*80.

**512*512**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuRWo.png

**80*80**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvID9.png

for left align the image:

```
  view.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

There is no way to centre the title with left align image. Temporally you can change titleEdgeInsets to do that:

```
  view.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 16, 8, 4)
```

OR

You can take a imageView to the left of button. And remove the image as part of button. then centre align the contentHorizontalAlignment.

**Code:**

```
  let customFacebookButton: UIButton = {
        let view = UIButton()
  //      view.setImage(UIImage(named: "logo"), for: .normal)
      //  view.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 4)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        view.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14),
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white ]
        let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Continue with Facebook", attributes: attributes)
        mutableAttributedString.append(string)
        view.setAttributedTitle(mutableAttributedString, for: .normal)
        return view
    }()
    customFacebookButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 20, width: 300, height: 40)
    self.view.addSubview(customFacebookButton)

    let imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 12, y: 22, width: 38, height: 38))
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo")
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. Is there a simple way to left align the image, but center the text? Also, what is the explanation for having to scale the image myself? iOS doesn't scale it with .scaleAspectFit?

Comment: Have you got the solution.

Comment: I ended up going with the centered layout. Thanks for your help. I still don't know why the OS scaled the image to the correct size with .scaleAspectFit, but didn't adjust the frame?

Comment: then you can accept it as a correct answer I think so.